# I want to log all mqtt messages of the broker. How should I design schema of database. Avoiding dulplicate entries and fast searching

Tags: database, mqtt, mosquitto

I am implementing a callback in java to store messages in a database. I have a client subscribing to '#'. But the problem is when this # client disconnects and reconnect it adds duplicate entries in the database of retained messages. If I search for previous entries bigger tables will be expensive in computing power. So should I allot a separate table for each sensor or per broker. I would really appreciate if you suggest me better designs.

Comment: Each message has retained and duplicate  flags. Filter out message when one of them is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to wildcard with a single client is definitely an anti-pattern. The reasons for that are:

1. Wildcard subscribers get *all* messages of the MQTT broker. Most client libraries can't handle that load, especially not when transforming / persisting messages.
2. If you wildcard subscriber dies, you *will* lose messages (unless the broker queues endlessly for you, which also doesn't work)
3. You essentially have a single point of failure in your system. Use MQTT brokers which are hardened for production use. These are much more robust single point of failures than your hand-written clients. (You can overcome the SIP through clustering and load balancing, though).

So to solve the problem, I suggest the following:

- Use a broker which can handle shared subscriptions (like HiveMQ or MessageSight), so you can balance all messages between many clients
- Use a custom plugin for doing the persistence at the broker instead of the client.

You can also read more about that topic here: http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-sql-database

Comment: That is really helpful

Comment: Thanks. If this solves your question, please set the question as resolved by marking the answer with a checkmark (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using QoS = 3 for all message to make sure one and only one message is delivered. Also you may consider time-stamp each message to avoid inserting duplicate messages if QoS requirement is not met.

Comment: There is no QOS 3, QOS levels can be 0, 1 or 2